# PowerShell Help - Add Length with formula to show in MB in Outout file

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

Here's my current script

```
get-childitem E:\Shares\Archive\Documents\Store -Recurse | 
where {!$_.PSIsContainer} | 
select-object Name, FullName, LastWriteTime, Length | 
export-csv -notypeinformation -path c:\temp\test2.csv | 
% {$_.Replace('"','')}
```

I would like to add another column to show the Length in MB or GB. So final output file would
show

File Name - Path - Last Mod Date - Length(KB) - Length (MB/GB)

Comment: So `select-object Name, FullName, LastWriteTime, Length, @{l='Length (GB)';e={$_.Length/1GB}}`

Comment: Instead of `where {!$_.PSIsContainer}` you can use the `-File` switch to filter only files.